# Eval Failure Is Not Handled

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a configuration file parser to be used in a BASH script. It has the basic shell syntax of assignment for variables, but there's also some extra validation to avoid accidental misuse. Everything is working in a successful scenario. However, when the eval fails, the method of handling the failure is not executed. I am at a loss as to why it wouldn't be handled. Below I have made a reduced example that demonstrates the issue I have encountered.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s -o nounset
shopt -s -o errexit
shopt -s -o pipefail
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s extglob
#shopt -s -o xtrace
IFS=$'\n\t'
 
 
function loadConf()
{
    local confFileLcl="$1"
    local lineLcl
    local optionLcl
    local valueLcl
 
    while IFS='' read -r lineLcl
    do
        lineLcl=${lineLcl%%#*}
 
        case "${lineLcl}" in
        *=*)
            optionLcl="${lineLcl%%=*}"
            valueLcl=${lineLcl#*=}
            valueLcl=${valueLcl//\"/}
            eval "${optionLcl}='${valueLcl}'" || echo  "Failed to set '${optionLcl}'."
        esac
    done <"${confFileLcl}"
}
declare -frt loadConf
 
# Create configuration file
echo -e "
var0=\"Value is set\"
var1=\"This is not an integer\"
" > "test.conf"
 
# Create variable that is to be configured to succeed.
declare var0="not-set"
# Create variable that is to be configured to fail.
declare -i var1=42
 
# Load the configuration file
loadConf "test.conf"
 
[[ "${var0}" == "Value is set" ]] || echo "Var0 check failed."
[[ "${var1}" -eq 42 ]] || echo "Var1 check failed."
```

I have tried various things to narrow down the issue, including disabling the enabled strict mode. This did not make a difference in the eval failure handling, only the type of error message printed.

Execution Output:

> ## $ ./demo.sh
>
> ## ./demo.sh: line 27: This: unbound variable

Line 27 is: eval "${optionLcl}='${valueLcl}'" || { echo  "Failed to set '${optionLcl}'." ; true; }

My expectation of the output would be:

> Failed to set 'var1'.
>
> Var1 check failed.

Running with trace:

```
$ ./demo.sh                               
+ IFS='                                   
        '                                 
+ declare -frt loadConf                   
+ echo -e '                               
var0="Value is set"                       
var1="This is not an integer"             
'                                         
+ declare var0=not-set                    
+ declare -i var1=42                      
+ loadConf test.conf                      
+ local confFileLcl=test.conf             
+ local lineLcl                           
+ local optionLcl                         
+ local valueLcl                          
+ IFS=                                    
+ read -r lineLcl                         
+ lineLcl=                                
+ case "${lineLcl}" in                    
+ IFS=                                    
+ read -r lineLcl                         
+ lineLcl='var0="Value is set"'           
+ case "${lineLcl}" in                    
+ optionLcl=var0                          
+ valueLcl='"Value is set"'               
+ valueLcl='Value is set'                 
+ eval 'var0='\''Value is set'\'''        
++ var0='Value is set'                    
+ IFS=                                    
+ read -r lineLcl                         
+ lineLcl='var1="This is not an integer"' 
+ case "${lineLcl}" in                    
+ optionLcl=var1                          
+ valueLcl='"This is not an integer"'     
+ valueLcl='This is not an integer'       
+ eval 'var1='\''This is not an integer'\'
++ var1='This is not an integer'          
./demo.sh: line 27: This: unbound variable
```

Comment: You forgot to tell us, which is line 26. Also, turn on `set -x`  so that you can see how your parameters are expanded.

Comment: I've updated it with the requested information.

Comment: Not completely. Where is the output from `set -x`?

Comment: Yeah, forgot that. Added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your trace shows what is going on. You would get the same error, if you would have written

```
eval "${optionLcl}=foo"
```

The problem here is that `optionLcl` expands to `var1`, and you have declared `var1` to be integer, which means that the right hand side is evaluated in numeric context.

In this case, an assignment

```
var1=foo
```

is interpreted (since `foo` is obviously not a number) as

```
var=$foo
```

This is similar to `echo $((a+b))`, which is interpreted as `echo $(($a + $b))`. But there is no variable named `foo` (or, in your case, no variable named `This`, because in your original program, the assigned value is *This is not an integer*). Because you have also turned on the *unset* option, this is killing you here.

The question remains, why the `|| echo ...` branch is not taken after `eval` stumbles over the error. Aftet all, a simple syntax error such as

```
eval ')'  || echo error
```

does display *error* (in addition to the error message from `eval`). A bit of experimenting shows that it seems that assignment in *numeric* context behaves differently from what we would expect. Example:

```
eval "abc=$((1+))" || echo error
```

does ONLY show the syntax error, but does not display *error*. The assignment or parameter substitution seems to be the crucial point:

```
eval ": $((1+))" || echo error   # Param expansion. Does NOT print "error"
eval "((1+))" || echo error      # No expansion. DOES print "error"
```

Whether this difference in behaviour is some obscure, but documented feature of bash, or simply a bug, is something I don't know.

**WORKAROUND**

Since you can not catch the error of assigning something non-numeric to a numeric variable (removing *unset* would simply let this error slip undetected, and having *unset* aborts your program), my suggestion is to separate the check from the actual assignment. You could do a

```
if eval "( ${optionLcl}='${valueLcl}' )"
then
  eval "${optionLcl}='${valueLcl}'"
else
  echo  "Failed to set '${optionLcl}'."
fi
```

The first `eval` uses a subshell, so an error is not propagated upwards, except via the exit code of the subshell, which is caught by `if`. However, since the eval happens in a child process, no variable would have been set in your script. Therefore, we repeat the `eval` in the `then` branch of the script, because we now know that we are safe.

Answer (score 0):

The `nounset` option, same as `set -u` doesn't mean "cause a command that evaluates an unset variable to fail". It means "terminate a non-interactive script entirely if an unset variable is accessed". So no other command has a chance to execute.  An interactive shell won't quit; internally it will do something like a `longjmp` to bail out of any recursions and return to the prompt.

The way to solve this is to check for the variable being set, and avoid the `eval` if it isn't.

To check whether a variable `var` is set, we can use the syntax `${var+y}`. If `var` is set (possibly empty, but set) this will expand to `y`. If `var` doesn't exist, it expands to nothing.

If the name `var` is held in a variable `varname`, we can do it with `eval`:

```
eval "exists=\${$varname+y}"

if [ $exists ] ; then
  eval "$othervarname=\$$varname"
else
  printf "%s: undefined variable\n" $varname
fi
```

I'm assuming here that `$varname` has been validated to be a valid variable name, and such a thing doesn't require quoting.

Comment: This is true. But those variables are present in the demonstration. Even adding those checks, the same error is displayed.

Comment: If you're seeing the error, it means you have an `eval` of an unset variable somewhere, where your code neglects to avoid the `eval` by checking for the unset variable.